# Unable to reference strings added under a new build variant in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, internationalization

I created a new build variant called "myVariant". I want to add translated strings only under the new variant. So, I created a folder called "myVariant" under `app/src/` and added translated resources under `app/src/myVariant/res/values-fr` and `app/src/myVariant/res/values-de` folders.

When I rename a string resource ID in the default `strings.xml`, Android studio does not rename the string resource ID in any of the translated files. When I click on a string resource ID in any of the translated files and find usages, it is not able to find any references.

When I click on `R.string.xyz` in Android studio, shouldn't it give me multiple implementations of `strings.xml` for the default and the translated files? Is it because I created it under a different build variant and it is not under `main`? Anyone seen this before? Any help will be appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

That was easy. Just switch the build variant in Android studio to "myVariant" and everything works.